# Form input value not changing based on selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a simple form dropdown button with 3 input selections.

I would like to make it so that when a user selects one of the selections, the value of that selection will be submit posted to my MySQL database. I had it working before but upon changing some settings it no longer works and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="evalsubmit.php" method="post" name="evaluationform">
<div class="btn-group col-lg-2">
  <div class="homeworkmenu">
      <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle homeworkselection" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Homework
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><input type="hidden" value="absent" name="homeworkeval"><a href="#">Absent</a></li>
           <li><input type="hidden" value="missing" name="homeworkeval"><a href="#">Missing</a></li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="incomplete" name="homeworkeval"><a href="#">Incomplete</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and my JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
              $(this).parents(".homeworkmenu").find('.homeworkselection').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
              $(this).parents(".homeworkmenu").find('.homeworkselection').val($(this).text());
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['evalsubmit'])) {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$evallevel = $_POST['evallevel'];
$homework = $_POST['homeworkeval'];
$classwork = $_POST['classworkeval'];
$general = $_POST['generaleval'];
$comments = $_POST['evalcomments'];
$evaldate = $_POST['evaldate'];
$oraleval = $_POST['oraleval'];
$selection = $_POST['selection'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($selection == 'mathselection') {
    $table_name = 'mathdb';
} elseif ($selection == 'readingselection') {
    $table_name = 'readingdb';
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (firstname, lastname, level, homework, classwork, general, comments, oraleval, evaldate, addedBy)
 VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$evallevel', '$homework', '$classwork', '$general', '$comments', '$oraleval', '$evaldate', '$user')";
}
```

At the moment, no matter what selection I select, be it "absent", "missing", or "incomplete", it writes the last selection, which in this case is "incomplete" into my database.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: are you sending this via AJAX?

Comment: @tereško yes I am aware of that, however, this website is only used internally by a very limited amount of people and IP blocked externally through .htaccess in a very confined environment. Therefore, at the moment, I'm just trying to get the core functionalities running ASAP

Comment: @2by2 nope. not AJAX.

Comment: then how do you submit this form?

Comment: @tereško damn dude, I'm in no way calling myself a web developer. I'm just learning what I can to help out my own company. No need to be so harsh. I finally understand why all my friends were against me asking for help on stackoverflow. Everyone here is so insecure that they feel the need to put others down (especially people who aren't as experienced or knowledgeable) just to fuel their ego a little more and perhaps feel better about themselves.

Comment: @ShaunY From time to time, people can be rude on this site, however this time you are being rude. People are asking questions because they want to clarify the issue to help you. Please provide more information if you want an answer, this is not a site where a group of people solve your problems for you. This site aims to build structured information on programming related problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you don't want to use the `<select>` tag? Seems like you might be hacking a substitute for it. Using `<select>` should solve the issue referred to in your question.

Might look something like

```
<select name="homeworkeval">
    <option value="absent">
       Absent
    </option>
    <option value="missing">
       Missing
    </option>
    <option value="incomplete">
       Incomplete
    </option>
</select>
```

Please be aware that my answer in no way addresses the SQL injection vulnerability that 2by2 brought to your attention.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good answer... But there is nothing related to "security" (the SQL possible injection on PHP side) here. ;) But +1 for the right answer about OP question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for the +1! The reason I said it should solve the Non security issues is that I chose not to address the sql injection since another user had already pointed it out.

Comment: Okay... I understand that you're not a native english speaker. ;) Your answer would be perfect without the last sentence of the first paragraph. ;)

Answer (score -1):

i will try to point you in the right direction

if you do

```
var homeworkeval = 1
homeworkeval = 2
homeworkeval = 3
```

what will the value of `homeworkeval` at the end be? ;-)

A solution would be

```
<input type="hidden" value="absent" name="homeworkeval">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a data-name="absent" href="#">Absent</a></li>
      <li><a data-name="missing" href="#">Missing</a></li>
      <li><a data-name="incomplete" href="#">Incomplete</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then js

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    // will be absent or missing or incomplete
    let name = $(this).data("name");
    $("[name='homeworkeval']").val(name)       
});
```

Comment: This is a good hint... But is not an answer ;)
I'm not the downvoter... But I could have been, since I agree...

Comment: actually, there is no question. and by the way my answer is describing the reason, why the last hidden field is written into the db. (because all hidden fields have the same name and the last wins)

Comment: I see.. I understand my problem now. Could I use a select element with options instead then?